# Syntax or format for URL location.search

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, http, w3c

Is there a syntax/format specified for the "search" part of the URL?

Is it alright to use like `?id!=123&(name=foo|name=bar)`?
Would this work in javascript/Spring framework or do I need to write a custom parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a syntax/format specified for the "search" part of the URL?

Yes.  The production rules for the `query` part are specified in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4).  I often find it is easier to look at the entire collection of production rules, which are grouped together in [appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)

```
query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )

pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"

unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
   
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

> Is it alright to use like ?id!=123&(name=foo|name=bar)?

The [VERTICAL LINE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7c/index.htm) is contrary to the standard; so you should percent encode it

```
?id!=123&(name=foo%7Cname=bar)
```

That should be fine.

I would be stunned if this did "just work" everywhere.  We have standards for that very reason.